# Ubuntu Mozilla Security, do I need this? General questions

Tags: updates, firefox, security, mozilla

I was searching for info on enabling/disabling javascript in firefox, some pages I need to have it function and without the java they're broke.

I came across this and was wondering is this something I should install? What is it? I'm totally new at this.

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu_mozilla_security

Comment: You came asking about A and wanna do B?

Comment: The question is about b, the security updates for mozilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description for that PPA clearly states:

> Mozilla Security/Stability **testing** archive for Ubuntu.

### So: No, don't install that!

I would:

1. Install [NoScript](https://noscript.net/) (I did this years ago and never looked back)
2. Disable JS everywhere, except on secure, trustworthy sites
3. Turn off the sound and notifications in NoScript: it becomes much less annoying after that!

### ;-)

Comment: OK thanks. I use noscript and ublock in FF. When I installed FF, all JS was disabled, I was unable to find a simple way to enable/disable, is there a plugin for that or is that what noscript does?

Comment: @Good_Guesser Yes, that's what NoScript does (ff plug-in)   **;-)** Question upvoted! You're a rep 8 user already now!